# Calculate proper latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta based on radius?

Tags: swift, swift4

Does anyone know of a mathematical way to calculate the proper latitudeDelta/longitude delta of a MapView region based on search radius? For instance, I give my users the option to search for items within a radius of 5, 10, 25, 50 & 100 miles. I would like the MapView region to accurately reflect that search radius and just show enough "map" to encompass the search radius.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about the latitude and longitude. Just convert from miles to meters and then create an MKCoordinateRegion by calling `init(center:latitudinalMeters:longitudinalMeters:)`, where the `latitudinalMeters` and `longitudinalMeters` are twice the radius, and use that, centered at the user's location, to set the map view's `region`.